# Is it appropriate to close questions on Meta in which users ask why their question is marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, meta

As I see, it is quite frequent to see some users asking a new question on Meta about why their question has been marked as duplicate (e.g., [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285792) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319672)), and most of them get closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253521/what-can-i-do-if-i-believe-that-my-question-was-wrongly-marked-as-a-duplicate), soon.

But I doubt (just doubt, not disagree at all) whether it is appropriate to close their questions on Meta immediately, because I believe in most cases they are seeking for a question-specific reason on why their questions got marked as duplicate, instead of a general procedure on how to reopen a question. And I think it is also appreciated to provide question-specific advice of editing to make their questions look less like duplicates.

Is it really necessary to close a question on Meta immediately if the question asks about the duplicate reason?

Comment: Clicking through all the duplicate links leads [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not) which makes no mention of posting on meta whatsoever. So my guess is the community has decided that questions seeking understanding on why a question was marked as a duplicate are off-topic for meta, or are otherwise unwanted.

Comment: @BoltClock it is probably also worth mentioning that advice in a [meta-tag:canonical] duplicate applies to meta questions themselves. That is, if asker of a meta question believes that generic explanation in dupe target is insufficient for their case, they can edit their meta question to explain this and have it reopened

Comment: Does everyone have to jump through the close-reopen hoop every time? That seems woefully inefficient.

Comment: Many an SO user asks a question, confident that he'll understand the answers and that he'll know how to use the provided info to solve his problem.  The more likely the question is a dup, the more likely that confidence is misplaced.  SO just isn't very fit to be a personal helpdesk that helps somebody catch up with a year or two of missing education.

Comment: Meta typically has plenty of opinion based answers. Marking a question straightforward as duplicate seems to me somewhat arbitrary and not very pedagogical. Personally I would not do it. As for the example you have shown it actually brings another problem. In how many ways can you phrase a question for which an answer already exists in SO? Is that way of phrasing not useful in itself for plenty SO users? Would it not be positive that you find the answer to your question using the phrasing you found best?

Comment: "Does everyone have to jump through the close-reopen hoop every time?" In my view, the main site at least would be vastly higher quality if everyone had to jump through that hoop - except instead of close-reopen, the close would be automatic, and it was just an "open" hoop.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Actually, I agree. Questions about why specific questions are closed are almost never exact duplicates of that question. It's helpful to link them, sure. It's even helpful to suggest them as a duplicate for the asker of the Meta question.

But more often than not, the users asking these questions on Meta want specific guidance and not a boilerplate FAQ entry. I believe we should stop immediately closing these questions as duplicates.

Comment: I Absolutely agree with this, I've seen a good number of actually Valid C++ Tickets get closed as duplicate before I can even reply. Often because the person closing them isn't as familiar as they think with the subject, such as Java programmers voting to close C tickets, python programmers voting to close Java tickets, etc.
Often seems someone posts it in chat and everyone jumps on the band-wagon without question.

Comment: @JohnBargman: What is a "ticket"? Stack Overflow is not a help desk. We have *questions*, not "tickets".

Comment: @NicolBolas A Ticket is a common mechanism for charting tasks and faults in industrial software development, my apologies for the incorrect wording, too much time working, not enough time thinking.
And Stack Overflow may not be a help-desk, but that's because help-desks rarely actually provide answers.

Comment: Once a question has been marked as a duplicate, there is apparently no recourse for the OP ... Other than banging their head against a desk ...

Comment: I have seen questions closed when it was clear what differentiated the closed question from the supposed duplicate. One can have substantial knowledge of a topic and still not have comprehensive enough knowledge to recognize such situations without thinking through the answer (to the point of actually writing said answer).

If nothing else, moderators should consider demonstrating a touch more humility, not least because of the situation described by @dsdsdsdsd: we need fewer headdesk moments....

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd: If the OP disagrees that their question is a dupe of the linked question they can respond in the comments &/or edit their question to make it clear why their question isn't a dupe. FWIW, if I think that the OP may not understand how to apply the linked answers to their specific question I'll try to give a short explanation in the comments.

Comment: @DerrellDurrett: If you disagree with a question closure (not just dupes) and you feel that you can assist the OP to improve their question to make it worth re-opening, then go for it! BTW, most question closures are performed by ordinary users, not diamond moderators. True, sometimes questions are dupe-closed to an imperfect dupe target, partly because it can be hard to find an exact match for common dupe questions; a language expert may see how their dupe target applies to the new question, but the struggling newbie may be unable to make the connection.

Comment: @PM 2Ring ... sure, true ... but the claimant can still leave their action in place .. just because I explain why it is not, does not force a removal of the action

Comment: ... and frankly I have witnessed only very little of the positive interactions that you describe ... from my point of view, Stack Overflow is the most negative computer-user forum that I have ever used ... it seems that having given users so much control has resulted in negativity rising to the top ..

Answer (score 10):

The first post you linked as an example was "I asked the question, was told the answer was somewhere else.  But now I want someone to answer the question exactly like I want it answered!"

This is basically asking the question again.

I can see 3 basic kinds of responses.

- We could re-answer the question here even though it was properly closed on SO itself.
- We could tell the user how to dispute their closing
- We could decide the user is right, it isn't a duplicate, and reopen it.

I think #1 is off-topic on SO: "I don't understand why my question is actually a duplicate.  Can someone re-answer my question on meta?"  Basically, why a question is a duplicate *is a duplicate of the original question*.

Do we want meta to be a court of second appeal for all closes?  If not, then #3 is off-topic for meta.

And #2 was already explained to the user.

So maybe they shouldn't be closed as a duplicate of the #2 canonical answer, but flagged as off-topic.  I don't see how this is better.

I suppose we could create a canonical answer to such a question saying "It was marked as a duplicate because your problem was answered by the other question's answers." and use that instead of "here is how to dispute a duplicate".  Again, I don't see how that helps.

Comment: Now I'm a little confused. Until now I thought a question was a duplicate if there was another question that asked the same - not another question that has an answer that is also an answer to this question. Is it in both cases a duplicate?

Comment: @Rhayene When a question is closed as a duplicate the automatically inserted text says "This question already has an answer here:", suggesting that it's the answers, and not the questions, that are relevant to the decision (that box is also shown to the person who asked the question when a duplicate is suggested, but the question hasn't received the required number of close votes yet). Honestly, I think it would be useful if 1. there was an official post from SE staff explicitly stating this that could be pointed to and 2. we changed the term duplicate.

Comment: @Rhayene If there isn't an answer to the question in the "duplicate" that solves this post's problem, then it is not a valid duplicate.  If there is an answer to the question in the other question's answers, then it isn't in dispute that in nearly every case the other question is a duplicate.  I hold it sufficient: others don't.  Basically, the goal of duplicates is to redirect questions to good solutions without copy/pasting them.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) post has a slightly different interpretion - or I just interpret it wrongly?

Comment: @Yakk is SO different from [other sites](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3638/a-friendly-reminder-that-duplicates-should-be-the-same-question-not-different-q)? I dont't want to argue - I just want to understand.

Comment: @Rhayene There are differing opinions on SO alone about what a "duplicate" is, let alone across the network. Each site is its own little community and they can, to an extent, determine how they want to use the features available to them for themselves. I believe - based on blog posts and other announcements for changes to closing as duplicates - that the SE staff's intention is that questions are duplicates based on **answers**, not the strict content of the question (applying some common sense, obviously).

Comment: @Rhayene "it’s not OK to close it as a duplicate of a twenty-seven page guide to netmasks": Shog9's advice seems to be "if the other question's answers are not a GOOD answer to this question, don't close as a duplicate". Here (“What does the IP address 128.0.1.1/24 mean?” it’s OK to close that as a duplicate of a more general question like “What do IP addresses of the form a.b.c.d/e mean?”) we have an example where the questions are different (one is more specific) and the duplicate is ok.  The problem is you can use duplicate to link a *poor* answer to *this* question that *somewhat* matches.

Comment: @Yakk but we often see that the OPs don't understand how this other question is relevant for them so these cases would not match " It depends how easy it is to figure out one example from the other. If it's only a matter of changing some numerical values or some variable names, they're duplicates. If understanding why the questions are at all related requires a detailed explanation, the questions aren't duplicates, merely related." from [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled). But your example would match.

Comment: @Rhayene To be honest, I've been around SO long enough - and have therefore become jaded enough - to think that the OP doesn't understand how it's relevant to them because they don't actually want to try. A lot of them just want code they can copy/paste out of an answer into their code.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist would it make sence to start a question about what qualifies a question to be a duplicate on SO then (if it does not already exists - my Google-Fu did not find one though)?

Comment: As an enthusiastic duplicate-closer and [wielder of Mjölnir](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212), @Rhayene, I have absolutely no problem re-opening a duplicate question where the poster has edited it to explain why the other does not apply. _This includes_ a situation where _they can't figure out_ why it applies: "I'm trying to do X and found this question Q, but don't understand why the answer says I need Y and Z. I should only need Z and W, right?" is a perfectly acceptable post to my mind.

Comment: This does need to be a real, fully-considered explanation of why the questions are different, however, not just "my question is obviously different because I'm asking about `MutableFloo`, not `Floo`, you moron mods".

Comment: Meta *can be* a court of second appeal for any close that's necessary. Removing *that* option is a terrible idea. It shouldn't be the first resort, but if edits and comments on the question have gone nowhere, sure, a good meta question is entirely allowable. [tag:specific-question], after all.

Comment: hmm, I wonder if this reversal of evidence is some kind of educational measure - so that people do more research in the first place.

Comment: I guess this is all expression of laziness on both sides. Askers want the specific reasons without checking the general duplicate evidences first and answerers on meta don't want to give specific reasons and rather prefer deflecting to a general and non-specific treatment. Both are shortcomings.

Comment: @Rhayene forget what everyone says, believe in the monkey. [*"Remember: duplicates are questions that ask for a solution to fundamentally identical problems - **many questions have similar or identical answers but are not duplicates**. By the same token, many questions are asked using very different wordings but seek to solve identical questions - closing these helps folks find their way to a solution even when they don't know what terms to search for."*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/213575)

Comment: @Braiam uh, I'm not a native - if the monkey is some kind of idiom I do not understand ^^

Comment: @Rhayene [Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post) has a monkey avatar.

Comment: @Rhayene check the avatar of the author of that post.

Comment: ahhh ok, I did not see that ^^

Answer (score -1):

In respect to all who give their time to help others:

@Gstestso, it's like something, you can't ask somebody to do your work. On one point, I agree the OP should get a chance to edit a question. Sometimes it happens, when you are not good in writing English, you tend to write something which either you don't mean to write or someone who misjudge the question.

So I believe they should be allowed to edit their question. If they are not doing it, it will result in closing of the question after a specific time.

But yes, I totally agree. If seriously looking for an answer you should do some search at least and then ask questions.

Comment: Closed questions can still be edited, and editing them puts them in the queue to be considered for reopening. Thus, there already is such a chance to edit.